# Bug or not: on android mobile browser flash always overlay on html div

Tags: android

I notice on android mobile browser, the flash content always overlay on top of everything regardless how the wmode be setted up. However it looks fine on android tablet.

Anyone has a clue, how could I config to make html div over flash on mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a consequence of how the Android browser renders Flash content/how Flash for Android works.  See these two bug reports:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8938 (Android)
https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-4684 (Adobe)

If it looks fine on a tablet, then this may be fixed in 3.0, but I doubt you'll find any way around it in earlier versions of Android.

Comment: Thx Mitch, you are right, I try a lot of different way to embedded flash and change the configuration parameters, I could not find a way around it on android 2.2. I do not have any 2.3 devices, so i don't know how it looks on android 2.3.