# Flash Player plugin inside WebView draws on top of views that should have been on top of the Flash Player

Tags: android, webview, flash

It's easier to explain by picture. Sorry for the censoring.

[image: screenshot]

In this screen there is a `WebView` which is the white part, containing a web page which has Flash content. The flash content should be below (partially hidden behind) the bottom red bar, because the webview bounds does not reach the bottom of the screen, only just above the bottom red bar. It works correctly on Android 4.0, but not on 2.3.7 (where the screenshot was taken from).

On the hierarchy viewer, it's clear that the red bar is on top of the webview.

```
--+--0 WebView-----------------------0 FlashPaintSurface
  |
  +--1 LinearLayout (bottom red bar)
```

Why does the FlashPlayer does not honor the bounds of the WebView? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I don't think that there is a real way to fix it... you could experiment a bit - try putting an identically sized but transparent view on top on the webview and then put the red bar on top of that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4430350/437226) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6523187/437226).

It's a known issue (reported as a bug in some cases).  There are no known workarounds except to [disable the flash plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9513454/437226).

Comment: I've been down the same road and this would have been my answer as well.